# Square matrices such that $A = B + C$ with each matrix diagonalisable. Must $B$ and $C$ commute?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A, B, C$ are square, real, symmetric, positive semi-definite matrices such that
$$
A = B + C
$$
and $A$ is positive definite.

Must $B$ and $C$ be simultaneously diagonalisable?

I'm thinking no, but can't find a counter example.

Comment: *Hint*: Try $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: Note that $B$ and $C$ are diagonalisable since they are symmetric. With that, $B$ and $C$ being simultaneously diagonalisable is equivalent to $BC = CB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad C = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
give a counter-example.